# C Enum is all Zeroes

Tags: c, enums, printf, zero

I'm rather confused.

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef enum
{
    INTEGER,
    NUMBER,
    FLOAT,
    CHAR,
    ARRAY,
    STRING
} enumType;

typedef struct intType
{
    enumType type;
    int width;
    int value;
} Integer;

typedef struct fltType
{
    enumType type;
    int width;
    double value;
} Float;

Integer make_int(int val)
{
    Integer tmp;
    tmp.type = INTEGER;
    tmp.width = 32;
    tmp.value = val;
    return tmp;
}

int get_int(Integer val)
{
    int tmp = val.value;
    return tmp;
}

Float make_float(double val)
{
    Float tmp;
    tmp.type = FLOAT;
    tmp.width = 32;
    tmp.value = val;
    return tmp;
}

double get_float(Float val)
{
    double tmp = val.value;
    return tmp;
}

int main(void) {

    Integer i = make_int(42);
    printf("Type: %d\nWidth: %d\nValue: %d\n", (int)i.type, i.width, get_int(i));

    Float f = make_float(42.8);
    printf("Type: %d\nWidth: %d\nValue: %f\n", (int)i.type, i.width, get_float(f));

  return 1;

}
```

This should output six lines, where the two "types" differ. INTEGER and FLOAT from the enumType.

Instead...

```
Type: 0
Width: 32
Value: 42
Type: 0
Width: 32
Value: 42.800000
```

Both are 0.

Even if I modify the enum, so both numbers are definitely different, it still doesn't work:

```
typedef enum
{
    INTEGER = 0,
    NUMBER,
    FLOAT = 1,
    CHAR,
    ARRAY,
    STRING
} enumType;
```

I have no idea what's going wrong.

Comment: You are printing `i.type` both times. Ofcourse they are zero both times

Comment: Check closer what you're printing in the second `printf` call.

Comment: It is all because you are using `i.type` instead of `f.type` for second `printf()` call.

Comment: In your last `enum` definition, what value do you suppose will be assigned to `NUMBER`?

Comment: Note: Never use casts unless they 1) are absolutely necessary **and** 2) you fully understand all implications **and** 3) accept them. There is no need to cast the `.type` for `printf`.

Comment: Said that a 10000 times (including to myself), but here again: **be very careful with copy & paste**.

Comment: I'm an idiot... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in the second `printf`

```
printf("Type: %d\nWidth: %d\nValue: %f\n", (int)i.type, i.width, get_float(f));
```

to

```
printf("Type: %d\nWidth: %d\nValue: %f\n", (int)f.type, f.width, get_float(f));
```

Comment: *face palm* Thanks.